# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Serialization of

Tags: php, yii, xampp

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Serialization of 'SimpleXMLElement' is not allowed' in C:\xampp\htdocs\t9l_loyaltyprogram\common\lib\Yii\web\CHttpSession.php:138 Stack trace: 
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\t9l_loyaltyprogram\common\lib\Yii\web\CHttpSession.php(138): session_write_close() 
#1 [internal function]: CHttpSession->close() 
#2 {main} Next exception 'Exception' with message 'Serialization of 'SimpleXMLElement' is not allowed' in C:\xampp\htdocs\t9l_loyaltyprogram\common\lib\Yii\web\CHttpSession.php:138 Stack trace: 
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\t9l_loyaltyprogram\common\lib\Yii\web\CHttpSession.php(0): session_write_close()
#1 [internal function]: CHttpSession->close() 
#2 {main} Next exception 'Exception' with message 'Serialization of 'SimpleXMLElement' is not allowed' in C:\xampp\htdocs\t9l_loyaltyprogram\common\lib\Yii\web\CHttpSession.php:138 Stack trace: 
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\t9l_loyaltyprogram\common\lib\Yii\web\CHttpSession.php(0): session_write_close() 
#1 [internal function]: CHttpSession->close() 
#2 {ma in C:\xampp\htdocs\t9l_loyaltyprogram\common\lib\Yii\web\CHttpSession.php on line 138
```

how to fix this issue i'm unable to find any answer

Comment: Are you trying to store a SimpleXml Object in session?

Comment: what is your code? And where are getting this error?

Comment: @fracsi yes i'm storing simplexml object in session

Comment: So that is your problem. To say it simple: you cannot store the object in session. As the error message states, the SimpleXml object cannot be serialized.

Comment: so what is the solution. I have to store data in session

Comment: Store the xml string instead.

Comment: ok,I will try it then let you know.thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. I corrected it using an array of session

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($output['tab_displayId'] as $id_display => $id_param){
                $test = new ClParaWidget($id_param, $id_display);
                $output[$id_display] = $test->toString($id_display);
                if (Yii::app()->session['S' . $id_display] != $output[$id_display])
                    Yii::app()->session['S' . $id_display] = $output[$id_display];
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I give more explanation. If I want to save in a session value an array:

```
Yii::app()->session['data'] = $array_data;
```

sometimes, this code returns an error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Serialization of 'SimpleXMLElement' is not allowed' in C:\xampp\htdocs\t9l_loyaltyprogram\common\lib\Yii\web\CHttpSession.php:138 Stack trace:
```

for that, I propose to use a array of session like here:

```
foreach ($array_data as $id => $data)       
  Yii::app()->session['S_' . $id] = $data;
```